# Many to Many relationship in grails

Tags: java, grails, grails-orm

I am trying a many to many relationship example in grails/Gorm. Below is the code what i tried so far.When i am trying to analyze a different scenario i would like to know how Gorm hibernation takes care of it.

```
 class Author {
   static hasMany = [books:Book]
   String name
 }

 class Book {
   static belongsTo = Author
   static hasMany = [authors:Author]
   String title
 }

 And in my controller i defined this way in order to add Authors and books.

 def a=new A(name:"ABC")
 def b=new B(title:"Code1")
 a.addToB(b)  
 def a=new A(name:"ABC")
 def b=new B(title:"Code2")
 a.addToB(b)         //It works.

 In the databaselevel it creates

 Table Author        Table Author-Book        Table Book
 id name               id   id                 id    Book
 1  ABC                1     1                 1     Code1
 2  ABC                2     2                 2     Code2

But what i want is the below format:

Table Author        Table Author-Book        Table Book
 id name               id   id                 id    Book
 1  ABC                1     1                 1     Code1
                       1     2                 2     Code2
```

How can i achieve this when i set name of the author to unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your domain setup is good. You are explicitly creating two authors (with the same name). I would change your code to

```
def a=new A(name:"ABC")
 def b=new B(title:"Code1")
 a.addToB(b)  
 def a= A.findOrSaveByName("ABC")       // this will attempt to query the db first and only create new record it already doesn't exist
 def b=new B(title:"Code2")
 a.addToB(b)         //It works.
```

Comment: Hi Elixir if i add one more column Age  and set name to unique for authors domain class and when i add below lines in my controller:      
     def a =new A(name:"ABC",age=40);

Comment: Hi Elixir if i add one more column Age  and set name to unique for authors domain class and when i add below lines in my controller:      
     def a =new A(name:"ABC",age=40);
           a=A.findOrSaveByName("ABC")                     
           a.save(flush:true)        //It pushes only the name and age as 
                                                 null.If i want to pass the age value too 
                                                 how should i change the dynamic 
                                                 finder method.

Comment: use A.findOrSaveByNameAndAge("ABC", 40)

Comment: Hi Elixir i am looking for some guidance on many to many relationship with extra column and below is the link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49509354/duplicates-to-be-allowed-in-the-mapping-table-for-many-to-many-relationship-with/49513301#49513301